# Multiple series area chart. Data from one single var, is it possible?

Tags: highcharts

I am getting into Highcharts little by little i am stuck at an aparently simple problem...

I have an area chart with 2 series.

```
$(function() {
    $('#grafico3a').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Series1',
            data: Series1,

        }, {
            name: 'Series2',
            data: Series2,
        }

        ]   
    });
});
```

the data file is this:

```
var  Series1 = [
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   0   ),  243 ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   1   ),  21  ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   2   ),  377 ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   3   ),  70  ],
];

var Series2 = [
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   0   ),  2880    ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   1   ),  3460    ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   2   ),  3090    ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   3   ),  980 ],
];
```

It works perfectly but now  i am trying to change it so to read series from single lines.. something like this:

```
var  Series = [
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   0   ),  243, 2880 ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   1   ),  21, 3460 ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   2   ),  377, 3090 ],
[Date.UTC(2003,8 ,24,   3   ),  70, 980  ],
];
```

Probably it is very simple but i cannot make it work!!

Can anyone help me, please???

Thanks!

Peter.

Comment: I don't think it is possible: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Thanlks Raeen.. i will use CSV instead...

Comment: Why do you want to use one variable? Do you want to reduce the data amount from the backend? In that case you can use format you suggested, but later you will need to split data into two separate variables (or array) to fit Highcharts requirements.